# In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm seeing this message on my app details for a version that is in "ready for upload" status:

"In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review."

I had submitted the binary (and then put it into "developer rejected" status), for the purpose of testing in-app purchases. From everything I've read so far, if you have both your app binary and app purchase in "waiting for review" status, they will go in together.

What is the best option?

```
1) Submit the app for review despite the message
2) Submit the app, then developer reject it, then see what I can do about change the message
```

Answer (score 18):

You can't change IAPs for your app once you say "Ready to Upload Binary". There's no undo really for this state either. What you can do is submit the binary from Xcode, wait for the status to switch to "Waiting for Review", then reject it, then wait for it to switch to "Developer Rejected", then set your IAPs, then click "Ready to Upload Binary" again, and upload it again.

Comment: It's hard to believe this is necessary/works, but ... there you go.

Comment: What I love about Apple is how intuitive its user interfaces are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think submitting the app and then rejecting it will solve your problem, because then it will just go back to the original "Ready for Upload" state you are currently at. I would just try submitting it and seeing whether or not it gets approved. If it does, congrats, and if it doesn't you should then have to option to change stuff and let them know there are in-app purchases involved.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, option 2 seems to have worked out ok. When the status changes to "developer rejected", it allowed me to edit the in-app purchase field and add my in-app purchase - something which I needed to do anyway.

Comment: I did not think it would allow you to edit that field after you reject. I thought it would just keep everything the same and allow you to resubmit a new binary. Glad to hear it worked out for you!