# itunes connect in app purchase issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I submited the app to for review...and i forgot to add the in app purchase for the version. Naturally the app was rejected for this reason.

Now my problem is this: I cannot add the in app purchase to this version because

> In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has
>   already been submitted for review. To manage your In-App Purchases, go
>   back to the App Summary page and click on the Manage In-App Purchases
>   button.

but i can't submit a new app version...because this version wasn't actually submited so i can update it.

Do i need to delete the app and readd it to iTunes Connect or is there a workaround this?

Comment: Just remove it and add a new binary...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309829/1270586)

It's basically:

1. Upload your binary
2. Wait until it's "Waiting for review"
3. Reject the binary yourself (app version > binary details >reject binary)
4. Wait until it's "Developer rejected"
5. Go add your in app purchases
6. Resubmit the binary

Comment: this works if you have no in-app already but if you have one already you cannot delete it or you will have to create another one with another bundle ID. Apple should refrain from doing anything for the web. Apple should buy Google just to get their html team because the citric company is inapt to create anything for the web. iTune Connect is a flaming piece of crap.

Comment: Can't agree more with SpaceDog. We lost 3 weeks now already with this non working system of theirs.