# Add in app purchase with the app on apple developer portal

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am working on an app, in which I have added in app purchase. When I try to add that in app purchase with the application then I am getting following message.

[image]

**But I didn't submit the application, Its current status is "Waiting for Upload".**

I want to add 3 types of In-App-Purchase with the application. 
What should I do now ?

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not add in-app purchase in "Waiting for Upload" state, you have to change the status to "Ready to upload" for adding in-app purchases.

For changing the state you have to submit the app and when status changes to "waiting for review" you have to reject the app and status changes to "developer rejected" and then you can add in-app purchases and change the status accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For submitting for review Seems like the only time you will be able to select an IAP item in the "View Details" page of your app's new version is when the App Status is in "Ready to Upload Binary" or "Binary Rejected".

So what I did was reject my binary and deleted the IAP item and then add the IAP item again in Manage In App Purchases. Need to give it a new ID though, but no biggie for me.

After that, you should be able to select the IAP item in View Details page. And THEN, press "Ready to Upload Binary"...

Hope this helps someone.

Please go through the following links

[In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366184/in-app-purchases-cannot-be-added-to-this-version-because-it-has-already-been-sub/10366377#10366377)

[Adding a in-app purchase while "Waiting For Upload"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010437/adding-a-in-app-purchase-while-waiting-for-upload)

[In-App Purchases cannot be added to this version because it has already been submitted for review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040916/in-app-purchases-cannot-be-added-to-this-version-because-it-has-already-been-sub)